# How to fix zsh: command not found: curl --digest error while running curl on zshell?

Tags: curl, zsh

```
curl --digest -u 'username:password' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/private/' -data '["foobar"]'
```

Error

```
zsh: command not found: curl --digest
```

echo $SHELL

```
/bin/zsh
```

I am not sure of what the error is or how to resolve. I do have curl installed on my MAC for example:

```
curl 'www.google.com' -v works correctly.
```

Comment: _command not found_ means that there is no executable of this name in any of the directories listed in _PATH_.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, please share the CURL version!

Comment: curl --version
curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) libcurl/7.64.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.39.2

Comment: Same version here, are you sure the first codeblock is the command your trying to run?

Comment: @user1934428 How do I know which dirs zshell is searching? How do I explicitly update that list?

Comment: @JRBobDobbs: Like **every** shell does: By looking at the `PATH` environment variable. What is particular for zsh, is, that you can alternatively use the array variable `path` (zsh keeps both in sync automatically). I personally find dealing with the array stored in `path` easier than with the string stored in `PATH`.  So you could do a `echo $path`  to see the list of directories and add those which are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my Mac, and it turned out that I had some non-breaking space whitespace characters in my curl command (I'd been storing it in the Mac notes application). I copied the command I was using into a scratch file in Intellij where the characters became visible.